# CSS fading animation timing off

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

so I'm trying to fade 3 images, one on top of each other slowly so you can see each image for a few secs before the next one fades on top. I'm following [this tutorial here.](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) However for some reason my images seem to fade over each other too fast and I can't control the timing well.

**[Here is my preview page.](http://leongaban.com/_stack/css_animation/cssbanner.html)** You are suppose to see a bird, then tomatoes then a boat, but right now it just all fades on top of each other and ends up on the boat.

I'm following Demo 1 and Demo 3, any ideas why my animation is off? Thanks in advance! :)

**My jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/TPjWG/

**CODE:**

```
<style>

@-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:1;
 }  
 50% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:1;
 }  
 50% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:1;
 }  
 50% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}       

#cf4a {
    position:relative;
    height:250px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#cf4a img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}

#cf4a img {
    -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;

    -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-duration: 30s;

    -ms-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-animation-duration: 30s;                
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;     
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;    
    -ms-animation-delay: 0; 
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;       
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;  
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 60s;       
    -moz-animation-delay: 60s;      
    -ms-animation-delay: 60s;       
}

</style>

<div id="cf4a">

    <a href="http://http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/bird1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/tomato2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/boat3.jpg" /></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe part of your issue is `z-index` ordering during the animation and lack of overlap in the timing of the animations (in relation to that `z-index`).

Using a fade-out only technique (since you appear to be doing a one time animation of the images). I have a solution with [**a working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TPjWG/20/) tested in Firefox and Chrome (IE9 does not support animations, so you must be gearing up for IE10 with your initial use of `-ms-` extensions). Since I am only fading out once, no animation is needed on the final `a` tag, as it is unveiled last and remains (and is the default for non-CSS3 animating browsers).

The demo uses the following CSS code (same HTML as your original):

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeOut1 {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 100;
 }  
 80% { /* 6 sec trans on 30s animation */
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 100;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:0;
   z-index: 100;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cf4FadeOut1 {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 100;
 }  
 80% { /* 6 sec trans on 30s animation */
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 100;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:0;
   z-index: 100;
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cf4FadeOut1 {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 100;
 }  
 80% { /* 6 sec trans on 30s animation */
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 100;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:0;
   z-index: 100;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeOut2 {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 2;
 }   
 90% { /* 6 sec trans on 60s animation */
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 2;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:0;
   z-index: 2;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cf4FadeOut2 {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 2;
 }   
 90% { /* 6 sec trans on 60s animation */
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 2;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:0;
   z-index: 2;
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cf4FadeOut2 {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 2;
 }   
 90% { /* 6 sec trans on 60s animation */
   opacity:1;
   z-index: 2;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:0;
   z-index: 2;
 }
}

#cf4a {
    position:relative;
    height:250px;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#cf4a a {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    z-index: 0;
}

#cf4a a {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;

    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;

    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0;   
}

#cf4a a:nth-of-type(1) {
     -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeOut1;
     -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeOut1;
     -ms-animation-name: cf4FadeOut1;

     -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 30s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 30s;           
}

#cf4a a:nth-of-type(2) {
     -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeOut2;
     -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeOut2;
     -ms-animation-name: cf4FadeOut2;

     -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 60s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 60s;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In the back of my head I knew this could be done :D

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle and demo page you have the images wrapped in `<a>` tags.  This causes the error to be in your use of :nth-of-type().

All your images are being affected by the :nth-of-type(1)
declaration since they are all 'first-child' elements within the `<a>` tags.

Comment: ah yeah thanks for pointing that out :) corrected, though still having animation keyframing problems :( I think I need to find out how to start a new animation after one finishes.

Comment: Yes, some tweaking/experimenting with keyframes/delay times is needed.  Even in the demo ('Demo with multiple images' section), the author states "it's not great" :)

Comment: Yeah going to keep trying to adjust the keyframes, maybe offer points or marked this one as unfixeable :(

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes and got it working slightly better than before. However, I still can't explain why the animation doesn't work properly when the image changes from the last one to the first one.

```
<head>
    <title> CSS alpha animation test </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />


</head>

<body>

    <style>

    @-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
     0% {
       opacity:0;
     }
     45% {
       opacity:0;
     }    
     55% {
       opacity:1;
     }
     100% {
       opacity:1;
     }
    }       

    #cf4a {
        position:relative;
        height:250px;
        width:300px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #cf4a img {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
    }

    #cf4a img {
        -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;     
    }
    #cf4a img:nth-of-type(1) {
         -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;   
    }
    #cf4a img:nth-of-type(2) {
         -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
    }
    #cf4a img:nth-of-type(3) {
         -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;       
    }

    </style>

    <div id="cf4a">

        <img src="http://leongaban.com/_stack/css_animation/img/bird1.jpg" />
        <img src="http://leongaban.com/_stack/css_animation/img/tomato2.jpg" />
        <img src="http://leongaban.com/_stack/css_animation/img/boat3.jpg" />

    </div>

</body>

</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Note that I have removed all the other code for the different browsers and just left the webkit code because I was testing this on chrome. I also changed the percentages complete as in their examples and that made a bit of a difference.

Comment: when I use 45% {opacity:0;} the animation stays white for much longer

Comment: Sorry about the delay. After reading up some more on this, the keyframes mean that the image will be transparent for the first 45% and then opaque for the rest. My understanding of the first 45% means that it is transparent 45% of the 10 seconds that the image is shown. So 4.5 seconds or so. But it still doesn't explain the jump and why the first image is not shown properly.

Comment: @Leon and sarcastyx--the "jumping" and other odd display issues are a result of improper `z-index` of the `absolute` positioned images during points of the animation (which neither of you take into consideration in your animations). I've posted a solution that resolves those issues.

Comment: @ScottS, Thanks. Should have spotted that. Strange how in the example they never mention that without the z-index the images will jump.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try using jquery.

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');
//var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
//var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
//var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );
$active.addClass('last-active');
$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Comment: oh I'm a jquery noob still, but thanks I'll try this out later :)